# Subquery in LinqC#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Tengo una consulta en SQL Server así:

```html
SELECT distinct FFF.Codigo,FFF.Campo, FFF.Sector, An.Estatus

FROM 
(SELECT Empresa,Codigo,Campo,Sector, max(Fecha) as Fecha_analisis 
FROM Analisis
GROUP BY Empresa,Codigo,Campo, Sector
)FFF 

INNER JOIN Analisis AS An ON FFF.Empresa = An.Empresa And FFF.Codigo = An.Codigo AND FFF.Campo = An.Campo AND FFF.Sector = An.Sector AND FFF.Fecha_analisis=An.Fecha

WHERE An.Estatus <> 'L'
```

```html
Codigo  Campo  Sector  Fecha_analisis    Analisis   
123   12   1       2021-01-05         P      
123   12   1       2021-01-09         F      

//Resultado esperado
Codigo  Campo  Sector Fecha_analisis    Analisis    
123   12     1      2021-01-09        F
```

Y necesito pasarla a Linq C#, pero me manda el error:

**Error CS1941  El tipo de una de las expresiones de la cláusula join es incorrecto. No se pudo realizar la inferencia de tipos en la llamada a 'GroupJoin ArgumentNullException**

```html
IQueryable<ClassMuestra> item = null;
item = (from m in (from m in bd.Analisis
group m by new
{
Empresa = (m == null) ? 0 : m.Empresa,
Codigo = (m == null) ? string.Empty : m.Codigo,
Campo = (m == null) ? 0 : m.Campo,
Sector = (m == null) ? null : m.Sector,
Fecha_analisis = (m == null) ? null : m.Fecha
} into x
select new
{
Empresa = x.Key.Empresa,
Codigo = x.Key.Codigo,
Campo = x.Key.Campo,
Sector = x.Key.Sector,
Fecha_analisis = x.Max(e => e.Fecha)
})

join an in bd.Analisis on new { m.Empresa, m.Codigo, m.Campo, m.Sector, m.Fecha_analisis } equals new { an.Empresa, an.Codigo, an.Campo, an.Sector, an.Fecha } into AnalisisR
from an in AnalisisR.DefaultIfEmpty()

where an.Estatus != "L"

group m by new
{
Codigo = m.Codigo,
Campo = m.Campo,
Sector = (short)m.Sector,
Analisis = an.Estatus,
Fecha_analisis = m.Fecha
} into x

select new ClassMuestra()
{
Cod_Prod = x.Key.Cod_Prod,
Campo = x.Key.Campo,
Sector = (short)x.Key.Sector,
Analisis = x.Key.Analisis,
Fecha_analisis = x.Max(e => e.Fecha)
}).Distinct();
}
```

Comment: O bien usas la sintaxis tipo consulta o bien usas el estilo lambda. Una mezcla de ambos te generará error.

Comment: @fredyfx como sería en lambda?

Comment: Edita la pregunta, incluye todos los elementos necesarios para reproducir tu escenario y con todo eso podré darte una respuesta más acorde a lo que necesitas :)

Comment: @fredyfx ya he editado la pregunta, espero esa info ayude. Gracias

Comment: Al menos podrías poner por favor la estructura de las tablas que usas ya que las clases y sus atributos siguen con un flamante error 404: not found o.oU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo he resuelto lo dejo aquí por si a alguien mas le sirve.

**Los requisitos principales son: Los nombres de las propiedades, los tipos y el orden en los objetos anónimos a los que se une deben coincidir.**

```html
join an in bd.Analisis on new { m.Empresa, m.Codigo, m.Campo, m.Sector, m.Fecha_analisis } equals new { an.Empresa, an.Codigo, an.Campo, an.Sector, an.Fecha } into AnalisisR
from an in AnalisisR.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

El problema estaba en el atributo Fecha_analisis, debe llamarse fecha, exactamente igual al atributo de comparacion con la tabla que se esta haciendo join

```html
IQueryable<ClassMuestra> item = null;
item = (from m in (from m in bd.Analisis
group m by new
{
Empresa = (m == null) ? 0 : m.Empresa,
Codigo = (m == null) ? string.Empty : m.Codigo,
Campo = (m == null) ? 0 : m.Campo,
Sector = (m == null) ? null : m.Sector,
Fecha = (m == null) ? null : m.Fecha
} into x
select new
{
Empresa = x.Key.Empresa,
Codigo = x.Key.Codigo,
Campo = x.Key.Campo,
Sector = x.Key.Sector,
Fecha = x.Max(e => e.Fecha)
})

join an in bd.Analisis on new { m.Empresa, m.Codigo, m.Campo, m.Sector, m.Fecha } equals new { an.Empresa, an.Codigo, an.Campo, an.Sector, an.Fecha } into AnalisisR
from an in AnalisisR.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: Joooo! Que gusto ver que has logrado funcionar, tremenda sorpresa que me llevo, es la primera vez que veo que se puede mezclar ambos estilos de linq. Muchas gracias :)